# I am trying to print all possible combination by changing the place of operands `|` and `&`. How can I achieve this?

Tags: java, logical-operators

This is the code to print all possible expression by changing the position of logical operator.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Permute_All_List_Numbers 
{
    static void permute(int[] a, int k) 
    {
        if (k == a.length) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.print(" [" + a[i] + "] ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        } 
        else 
        {
            for (int i = k; i < a.length; i++) 
            {
                int temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;

                permute(a, k + 1);

                temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int N = 2;
        char[] sequence = new char[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            sequence[i] = ('|','&');

        System.out.println("The original sequence is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            System.out.print(sequence[i] + " ");

        System.out.println("\nThe permuted sequences are: ");
        permute(sequence, 0);

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

I am facing the error as shown below.
What to do.

> Permute_All_List_Numbers.java:42: error: ')' expected
>               sequence[i] = ('|','&');
>                                 ^ Permute_All_List_Numbers.java:42: error: not a statement
>               sequence[i] = ('|','&');
>                                  ^ Permute_All_List_Numbers.java:42: error: ';' expected
>               sequence[i] = ('|','&');

the 2nd error is

> Permute_All_List_Numbers.java:48: error: incompatible types: char[]
>   cannot be converted to int[]
>           permute(sequence, 0);

Comment: `sequence[i] = ('|','&')` -- What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I am using the logical operators or operator and and operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `char` array and are trying to resolve `('|', '&')` to an index. An element in a `char` array (Or any type of array) can only hold one element of the array's type. I believe what you want to do is have

```
char[] sequence = {'|', '&'};
```

as the decleration of the array and get rid of the for loop. This will make `|` as the first element of the `sequence` array and `&` as the second element.